# Kiel traduki "to be involved in"?

Tags: translation

En la lasta numero de la revuo *La Ondo de Esperanto* (februaro 2017), mi legis la jenan frazon:

> Mi mencios ankaŭ plurajn agadojn, en kiujn mi estas envolvita – ĉar tiujn mi plej bone konas.

Sendube, la intencita signifo de "envolvita" estas *involved*. Tamen, nek PIV nek ReVo apogas tiun uzon de *envolvi*. Nun, kiel oni povus traduki *to be involved in*?

Amuze, la respondo eble kuŝas en la sama numero de la Ondo. Kelkaj paĝoj sube, ja aperas la verbo "enplektiti", plej verŝajne en la senco de *to be involved*. En la Tekstaro, mi trovis plurajn uzojn de "enplektiti", "enplekti sin" aŭ "enplektiĝi" kun simila senco. Sed, denove, mi ne povas pravigi tiun uzadon surbaze de iu ajn vortaro.

Ĉu vi apogas "enplekt*" aŭ proponas alian elturniĝon?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Jes, la citita frazo evidente estas misinfluita de "involved", kaj en tiu senco la ĝusta esperanta vorto estas "partopreni":

> Mi mencios ankaŭ plurajn agadojn, *kiujn mi partoprenas* ...

(la frazo kun "partopreni" estas evidente pli mallonga kaj simpla).

Cetere, la angla vorto estas plursenca, kaj havas ankoraŭ aliajn, malaprobajn signifojn (to be involved in the crime; to make complicated; tangle) -- tiujn signifojn mi tradukus per "impliki, implikiĝi".

Answer (score 4):

Krom *partopreni*, oni ankaŭ povas uzi *enmiksi*, kvankam la signifo estas iom pli speciala. [PIV](http://vortaro.net/#enmiksi%20sin):

> **enmiksi sin**, **enmiksiĝi**. Sin miksi: *vi ne havas la rajton enmiksi vin en nian aferon*<sup>Z</sup>; *la infanoj enmiksis sin en la paroladon*<sup>Z</sup>; *precipe se en la aferon enmiksiĝas virino!*<sup>Z</sup>.

Answer (score 3):

Benson diras na “**be involved (in, with)**, (occupy self with), engaĝiĝi (en, pri)”, sed eble la espimo “ludi rolon (en, pri)” ne estus malbona.

Answer (score 2):

Mi dirus ***okupiĝi pri***.

La frazero *esti envolvita en ion* ja povus havi sencon, sed ne simple "involved." Mi komprenus tion kiel "to be wrapped up / entangled in something."

Comment: Laŭ mi, “okupiĝi” estas tro forta nocio, ĉar, laŭdifine, mi povas okupiĝi nur pri unu afero, sed mi povas ludi rolon en pluraj aferoj.

Comment: Laŭ PIV, “okupiĝi” signifas **Dediĉi sian atenton aŭ aktivecon al iu aŭ io**. Ĉu tio estas tro forta nocio en la kuntektsto, mi ne povas diri sen pli a kunteksto, sed certe ja eblas okupiĝi pri multaj aferoj samtempe.

Comment: Ŝmacas je servi du mastrojn.

Comment: Je mia matenmanĝo de ŝinko kaj ovoj – la kokino ludas rolon en ĝi, sed la porko okupiĝas pri ĝi.

Answer (score 0):

Revo:

> Partopreni = Preni sian parton de io: partopreni en festeno, kongreso, en la profitoj...

Comment: Laŭ mi “partopreni” estas tro forta nocio, taŭga nur por definitaj aranĝoj. Sed la koncerna nocio aplikiĝas ankaŭ al fako, ekzemple, la matematiko – se me, ekzemple, instruas la matematikon en la gimnazio, mi estas “involved in” la matematiko.